# the Database field must be set on Operation

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, dockerfile

I have a golang application with mongodb connected using mongo-driver.
Everything is working fine if I run the main file as `go run main.go`
It is able to connect to database as expected.

However if I dockerize the application it is unable communicate to the database whenever I hit the api that interacts with the database it exits with message

> the Database field must be set on Operation

Dockerfile

```
ARG ROOT="/go/src/bitbucket.org/myteam/myapp"
ARG BIN="/go/bin"

FROM golang:1.13 as build
ARG ROOT
ARG BIN
ENV GOBIN $BIN
ENV GOPATH /go
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install go-dep -y
RUN mkdir -p $ROOT
RUN mkdir -p $BIN
WORKDIR /go
COPY .env .
WORKDIR $ROOT
COPY src/bitbucket.org/myteam/myapp .
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "main.go"]
RUN dep ensure
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo

FROM alpine:3.10
ARG ROOT
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
RUN mkdir -p /go/bin
WORKDIR /go/bin
RUN mkdir -p /go/bin
WORKDIR /go/bin
COPY --from=build $ROOT/myapp myapp
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["./myapp"]
```

Connection File

```
config := conf.GetInstance()
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Second)
    var clientOptions *options.ClientOptions
    if config.MONGODB_USERNAME != "" && config.MONGODB_PASSWORD != "" {
        if config.Env == "dev" {
            clientOptions = options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://" + config.MONGODB_HOST + ":" + config.MONGODB_PORT).SetAuth(options.Credential{
                AuthSource: config.MONGODB_NAME, Username: config.MONGODB_USERNAME, Password: config.MONGODB_PASSWORD,
            })
        } else {
            mongoURI := fmt.Sprintf("mongodb+srv://%s:%s@%s", config.MONGODB_USERNAME, config.MONGODB_PASSWORD, config.MONGODB_HOST)
            clientOptions = options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURI)
        }
    } else {
        clientOptions = options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://" + config.MONGODB_HOST + ":" + config.MONGODB_PORT)
    }

    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)

    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal("Error connecting to database", err)
    }
    db := client.Database(config.MONGODB_NAME)
    Migrate(db, ctx)
    logrus.Info("Database connection successful")
    return db
```

Comment: Please show relevant code, especially how you are initializing the client. You are likely not calling `client.Database(...)` correctly.

Comment: @Marc updated but I am able connect and run without docker

Comment: How if your config loaded? There's no error returned there, so check that it is properly loaded and has the required fields.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when the mongodb database name is not available for the connection.

Make sure your `config.MONGODB_*` variables are available to set the connection string for mongodb.